# Save content to web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to `JavaScript` and web development. I'm practicing by making a to-do list application. I was wondering how I would go about saving the content of the list that was created into the browser. Right now if I refresh my page or exist the browser it will delete everything. I want to prevent that.

Comment: Google is your friend! Search for "jQuery localstorage" :-)

Comment: HTML5 local storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 0):

Even that this is a broad question I'll try to help you be asking you to try to use HTML5 web storage.

You can store for example easily in `locaStorage` any data you want.

You can learn more here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

It's also quite easy with JS:

```
// Store
localStorage.myValue = "Text";

// Retrieve
var myValue = localStorage.getItem('myValue');

// Delete
localStorage.removeItem('myValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `localStorage` to do that.

An example of an application you're working using `localStorage` can be found here

[How to use local storage for JavaScript](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-local-storage-for-javascript/)

You can learn more about [localStorage at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)